# Weird behaviour on emacs with running django server in terminal

Tags: spacemacs, python, shell, lsp

something weird is going on in my 'emacs-IDE'. I am editing some javascript files in a django project using spacemacs. Some tools I use are treemacs and lsp-mode.

In order to test my code I call up a shell using `spacemacs/default-pop-shell` and start the django server from there `python manage.py runserver`.

Now here comes the catch: when I edit some javascript code, e.g. uncomment a console.log() statement, the old code gets loaded even when I kill the server and restart it (which should not be required anyways). Is there some bug that makes emacs somehow cache and load the 'old' files? Seems like a stupid question, but I cannot think of another explanation why my edits do not get applied immediately.

```
document.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', function() {

    // Use buttons to toggle between views
    document.querySelector('#inbox').addEventListener('click', () => load_mailbox('inbox'));
    document.querySelector('#sent').addEventListener('click', () => load_mailbox('sent'));
    document.querySelector('#archived').addEventListener('click', () => load_mailbox('archive'));
    document.querySelector('#compose').addEventListener('click', compose_email);


    // Disable submit button unless recipients field and subject has some content
    document.onkeyup = () => {
        //console.log('buttonpressed');
        const recipientsValue = document.querySelector('#compose-recipients').value;
        const subjectValue = document.querySelector('#compose-subject').value;
        // console.log('Recipients:', recipientsValue);
        if (recipientsValue.length > 0 && subjectValue.length >0) {
            document.querySelector('#compose-submit').disabled = false;
            // console.log('enabled');
        } else {
            document.querySelector('#compose-submit').disabled = true;
            // console.log('disabled');
        }
    };
    // By default, load the inbox
    load_mailbox('inbox');
});

function compose_email() {

    // Show compose view and hide other views
    document.querySelector('#emails-view').style.display = 'none';
    document.querySelector('#compose-view').style.display = 'block';

    // Clear out composition fields
    document.querySelector('#compose-recipients').value = '';
    document.querySelector('#compose-subject').value = '';
    document.querySelector('#compose-body').value = '';
}

function load_mailbox(mailbox) {
    // Show the mailbox and hide other views
    document.querySelector('#emails-view').style.display = 'block';
    document.querySelector('#compose-view').style.display = 'none';

    // Show the mailbox name
    document.querySelector('#emails-view').innerHTML = `<h3>${mailbox.charAt(0).toUpperCase() + mailbox.slice(1)}</h3>`;
}
```

Above is the existing code in my /static/mail folder.

However, the line I last commented out is line 15: // console.log('Recipients" ...)

In the Inspector/Debugger in the browser the line shows as uncommented. I have since then reloaded the emacs instance. Same result...

Am I missing something here?